# Ryu, openflow v1.5, OFPET_BAD_ACTION, OFPBAC_BAD_OUT_PORT errors

Tags: openflow, ryu

When I run simple_switch_14.py application in mininet environment,  the ping of hosts works just fine.

Then I change the following strings of code:

1) "from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_4"   to   "from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_5"

2) "OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_4.OFP_VERSION]"   to   "OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_5.OFP_VERSION]"

3) "out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id, in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)"   to   "out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id, match=parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port), actions=actions, data=data)"

it means that I am trying to run this application in openflow 1.5 version environment.

I get following error:

EVENT ofp_event->SimpleSwitch14 EventOFPPacketIn
packet in 1 00:00:00:00:00:01 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 1
EventOFPErrorMsg received.
version=0x6, msg_type=0x1, msg_len=0x44, xid=0x703a0cc
 `-- msg_type: OFPT_ERROR(1)
OFPErrorMsg(type=0x2, code=0x4, data=b'\x06\x0d\x00\x38\x07\x03\xa0\xcc\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x16\x80\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x80\x00\x06\x06\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xff\xff\xff\xfb\xff\xe5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
 |-- type: OFPET_BAD_ACTION(2)
 |-- code: OFPBAC_BAD_OUT_PORT(4)`
-- data: version=0x6, msg_type=0xd, msg_len=0x38, xid=0x703a0cc
     `-- msg_type: OFPT_PACKET_OUT(13)

so, I am wondering, why it generates 'bad out port' error, what has changed in 'out ports' or in 'actions' between v1.4 and v1.5 of openflow protocols?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, passsp Do you have a solution for the problem?